# How can i get telnet output printed line by line?

Tags: python, telnetlib, cisco-ios

I have implemented a script that connects to a Cisco device and collects the show run output.

The script is:

```
import getpass
import telnetlib
import time


HOST = "10.62.149.9"
user = input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass("User Password: ")
enable = getpass.getpass("Enable Password: ")

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.write(b"enable\n")
if enable:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(enable.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.write(b"term len 0\n")
tn.write(b"show run\n")
time.sleep(10)
s = tn.read_very_eager()
print (s)
tn.close()
```

The script output is:

```
\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/26\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/27\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/28\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/29\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/30\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/31\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/32\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/33\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/34\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/35\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/36\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/37\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/38\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/39\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/40\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/41\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/42\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/43\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/44\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/45\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/46\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/47\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/48\r\n no switchport\r\n ip address 10.62.149.9
255.255.255.128\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/49\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/50\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/51\r\n!\r\ninterface GigabitEthernet1/0/52\r\n!\r\ninterface Vlan1\r\n no ip address\r\n shutdown\r\n!\r\ninterface Vlan10\r\n ip address 10.10.10.1
255.255.255.0\r\n!\r\ninterface Vlan199\r\n ip address 217.21.0.6 255.255.254.0\r\n no ip redirects\r\n ip ospf priority 100\r\n!\r\ninterface Vlan777\r\n ip address 7.7.7.1
```

**Question**

Is there a way to change the script so the output is presented line by line way?

Comment: Not a solution to your question, but wouldn't `pexpect ` do a much better job than trying to parse raw telnet?

Comment: Or `netmiko` as another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) isn't very clear about `Telnet.read_very_eager`, but it mentions that it reads and writes `bytes` for other methods. `type(s)` is probably `bytes`.

Use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to get a string: `print(s.decode('ascii'))` (use the appropriate encoding)

Note: This is for Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the string with some common special character that separates the lines using python split() function and after that initiate a for loop with the length of variable and then print.